# Can we define tangent spaces for $C^k$ manifolds via derivations or cotangent spaces?

Tags: manifolds, definition, smooth-manifolds

Wikipedia gives [three definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Formal_definitions) of the tangent space of a Manifold:

- Via tangent curves,
- Via derivations, and
- Via cotangent spaces.

For the last two, the manifold is assumed to be $C^{\infty}$, as opposed to the definition via tangent curves for which the manifold can be $C^k$.

**Can either of the last definitions be generalized to $C^k$ manifolds?**

Comment: A $C^k$ manifold can simply have the charts (uniquely) completed to become smooth without changing underlying manifold at all. Use the resulting (co)tangent bundle for the original $C^k$ structure as desired.